# Mosync: Display a transparent screen over another screen

Tags: c++, mobile-phones

**I am using Mosync API C++ for cross platform mobile development. I am trying to have a transparent screen(that does have one label in it that is not transparent) display itself over another screen, so I can see both screens at the same time.**

But what happens it that the screen is not transparent, its black? Why does that happen? I know that its possible to do this because Sams CookBook example of a Menu, is a transparent screen(with a listbox in it) & it displays over the top of another screen.

Why do you think my code below does not display a transparent screen but a black screen? My small project example is attached (including its transparent .png file):

```
#include <MAUtil/Moblet.h>
#include <MAUI/Screen.h>
#include <MAUI/Label.h>
#include <MAUI/Image.h>

using namespace MAUtil;
using namespace MAUI;

#define RES_BLANK 1

class ClearScreen : public Screen
{
    public:
        ClearScreen() : Screen()
        {
            Image *cell = new Image( 0, 0, 400, 800, NULL, true, true, RES_BLANK );
            Label *item = new Label( 10, 300, 200, 200, cell );

            // What SHOULD happen: have the whole screen transparent by having a
            // transparent Image as the background & have a pink label on this screen,
            // Then I should be able to also see parts of MyScreen behind this screen
            // because parts of this are transparent
            // What ACTUALLY happens:
            // This creates an Image that is black (that covers the whole screen)
            // & a pink label on it
            this -> setMain( cell );
        }

    private:
};

class MyScreen : public Screen
{
    public:
        MyScreen() : Screen()
        {
            Label *cell = new Label( 0, 0, 400, 800, NULL );
            Label *item = new Label( 0, 0, 200, 200, cell );
            cell -> setDrawBackground( true );
            cell -> setBackgroundColor( 20000 );
            item -> setDrawBackground( true );
            item -> setBackgroundColor( 90000 );

            this -> setMain( cell );
        }

    private:
};


class MyMoblet : public Moblet
{
    public:
        MyMoblet()
        {
            MyScreen *m = new MyScreen();
            m -> show();
            ClearScreen *c = new ClearScreen();
            c -> show();
        }

        void keyPressEvent(int keyCode, int nativeCode)
        {

        }

        void keyReleaseEvent(int keyCode, int nativeCode)
        {

        }
};

extern "C" int MAMain()
{
    Moblet::run(new MyMoblet());
    return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

When you calling the `show()` method it hides current screen. Here is the part from Screen.cpp source file:

```
void Screen::show() {
            ...
            if(sCurrentScreen) sCurrentScreen->hide();
            sCurrentScreen = this;
            Engine::getSingleton().setMain(mMain);
            mMain->setEnabled(true);
            mMain->requestRepaint();
            ...
    }
```

Just use Layouts and Labels with transparent colors.